# Convert Unicode string to a hexadecimal escape sequence using Python

Tags: python, unicode

For example:

```
>>> u = u'€€€'
>>> s = u.encode('utf8')
>>> s
'\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x82\xac'
>>> print s
€€€
```

But I want to get the string:

```
"%E2%82%AC%E2%82%AC%E2%82%AC"
```

as is sometimes required for URLs.

Currently I'm doing it byte by byte, as in:

```
>>> "%0X" % ord(u.encode('utf8')[0])
'E2'
```

Is there a simpler / more elegant way to do this?

Comment: you can do `u.encode('utf8').encode('hex')` to get the hex, but you'll need to do some more work to insert the desired '`%`'.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) module.

```
import urllib2
s = '\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x82\xac'
urllib2.quote(s)
```

Output:

```
'%E2%82%AC%E2%82%AC%E2%82%AC'
```

Answer (score 3):

Look to the quote function from urllib module http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote

```
>>> import urllib
>>> u = u'€€€'
>>> s = u.encode('utf-8')
>>> print urllib.quote(s)
%E2%82%AC%E2%82%AC%E2%82%AC
```